# gnuplot - plotting with loop

Tags: linux, gnuplot

I have a problem with a gnuplot script.

my data file, have the following format, (values are as example)

```
# timestamp        |- user1 -|       |-user2-|          |-user3-|
# ms            procs cpu% mem%   procs cpu% mem%    procs cpu% mem%
1234            10    12   13       20   22   23      30    32   33
1235            19    15   16       29   25   26      39    35   36
```

my gnuplot code is

```
reset

USERS="user1 user2 user3"

VAL(g,c)= (3*(g-1)) + c  

plot for [i=1:words(USERS)] "__GCRONDIR__/.data/usrstat.log" \
   u 1:VAL(i,3) t word(USERS,i)." cpu:".i  __STYLE0__, \
"" u 1:VAL(i,4) t word(USERS,i)." mem:".i  __STYLE0__
```

my problem is that the loop, happens only for the last user,
so if a have 10 users, lets say, this script, will plot 9 cpu's values,
for the first 9 users, and both values for the last one.
... for me make no sense, any one?

here a screen shot ;)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that gnuplot plots in loop only one line at once, and the second part of your loop is treated as a separate plot. Gnuplot first plots all "cpu" lines in a loop:

```
plot for [i=1:words(USERS)] "__GCRONDIR__/.data/usrstat.log" \
   u 1:VAL(i,3) t word(USERS,i)." cpu:".i  __STYLE0__, \
```

and then the last "mem" line:

```
"" u 1:VAL(i,4) t word(USERS,i)." mem:".i  __STYLE0__
```

You can use nested loops instead:

```
kind(k)=(k==1? "cpu: " : "mem: ")
plot for [i=1:5] for [j=1:2] (i-1)*2+j t sprintf("%s %d", kind(j), i)
```

[image]

For your case it would be something like this:

```
reset
USERS="user1 user2 user3"
VAL(g,c)= (3*(g-1)) + c  
kind(k)=(k==3? "cpu:" : "mem:")
plot for [i=1:words(USERS)] \
for [j=3:4] \
"__GCRONDIR__/.data/usrstat.log" \
   u 1:VAL(i,j) t word(USERS,i).kind(j).i  __STYLE0__
```

Comment: this format dont work, inside the script, i get exactly the straight lines, like your image, and this is wrong. I use the follow, using your code: 

plot for [i=1:words(USERS)] for [j=2:4] (i-1)*3+j t sprintf("%s %d", USR(j), i)
 -  (   USR(i)=word(USERS,i)   ) -        
But my 1st question still, is "why my script dont work, in theory is wright yes ?"

Comment: @prompt32 That was just example. See edited answer. Not having your data, I can't guarantee that it works.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/users/6401403/michael-o base on 
Michael O's answer, it works, and this is my whole script.

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot

reset
set term __TERM__ transparent truecolor enhanced font "__PLOTFONT__" size __PLOTGEOMETRY__
set key noreverse outside top right Right tc rgb"#ffffff"
set grid ytics xtics back lw __PLOTGRID__ lc rgb"#ffffff"
set autoscale

set title "Users %" tc rgb"#ffffff"
set xtics ("0" 0,"." 60,"." 120,"3" 180,"." 240,"." 300,"6" 360,"." 420,"." 480,"9" 540,"." 600,"." 660,"0" 720,"." 780,"." 840,"3" 900,"." 960,"." 1020,"6" 1080,"." 1140,"." 1200,"9" 1260,"." 1320,"." 1380,"0" 1440,) tc rgb"#ffffff"
set ylabel "%" tc rgb"#ffffff"
set ytics  tc rgb"#ffffff"

DATA="__GCRONDIR__/.data/usrstat.log"
USERS=system("__GCRONDIR__/bin/getEnv 'USERS'")

VAL(g,c)=(3*(g-1)) + c  
USR(i)=word(USERS,i)

STATLABELS="pad1 procs cpu mem"

kind(k)=word(STATLABELS,k)


plot for [i=1:words(USERS)] for [j=3:4] \
"__GCRONDIR__/.data/usrstat.log" u 1:VAL(i,j) t USR(i)." ".kind(j).i  __STYLE0__
```